Electric bike battery shutdown under load
I have built a custom electric bike with the following components from Amazon.
48 V 25 Ah Battery Pack
48 V 1000 W Brush DC Motor
48 V 1000 W Controller
The problem is the bike "shuts down" under load. It seems to be related to the amount of load on the motor. When a heavier rider such as myself is riding, it often shuts off soon after takeoff, or not long after as the bike comes up to speed. With a lighter rider, it can often get up to speed for a few runs before it shuts off.
When it shuts down, I've used a voltmeter to check the voltage of the battery pack while it's still connected to the controller, and it's zero. If I disconnect the battery pack and measure the voltage, it now reads about 50V. Re-connecting the battery will make the bike work again for a short time until the battery pack cuts out.
So my "guess" is the BMS has cut power for some reason. The battery pack Amazon listing claims:


Fit for motor: 48 V 250 W 300 W 350 W 500 W 650 W 800 W 1000 W motors
BMS: 30 A


... so perhaps the motor is drawing >30 A? I'm not sure.
The motor Amazon listing says:

Power 1000 W, voltage 48 V, rated current 27.5 A, speed max 3000 RPM

The controller is a "Yi-Yun YK33F", and the Amazon page is a bit light on details, but this AliExpress listing states 48 V 1000 W 30 A Brush DC Motor Controller.
I'm looking for suggestions on how to make this more reliable, or tips on troubleshooting.

Did I choose a battery pack that is not sufficient for this configuration?
Do I need some sort of solution to limit current draw by the motor?
I'm also not sure if the controller is part of the problem or not.


When starting, and in a high torque low RPM situation like accelerating from low speed, these motors can take a lot more current than nominal. So you can try going at the same speed, but with much lower acceleration in order to get to that speed. If that solves the problem, then you need a motor controller that is able to limit current to what the BMS allows.

"... the Amazon page is a bit light on details ..." That's the problem. The advice here is "No datasheet? No sale!" You have no warranty, nobody to contact and no adequate documentation. Each of these costs money to produce and that's why reputable suppliers charge more. You may be on your own with this one.

This seems to be about troubleshooting connected modules more than design/function principle of something electromagnetic or electronic-

@greybeard, no, this is about fundamental misconception that "rated current" of a motor is not the parameter for heavy acceleration mode or "stall current". This is a very important "function principle".

"Rated current 27.5 A" does not mean that the motor will never draw more than 27.5 A under any circumstances. What it means is, if your design allows the motor to draw more current than that, then you have no right to complain if the motor fails as a result.
